# Windows XP Service Pack 3 keeps freezing when saving a document

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office-2007

Hey Everyone. I just reloaded Windoes XP (Media Center Edition) onto my Wife's laptop. I updated to Service Pack 3. I've got Office 2007 running along with some other software.

It seems that when I go to save a document it freezes. the save windows tries to display but only partially displays and then gets stuck. I have to close the windows and reboot in order to get past this issue.

It seems to be an issue with using save as. If I simply hit save it works.

Has anyone seen this issue?

Thanks

Ken

Comment: How long does it freeze?  What is the longest you have waited for it to unfreeze?  Are there any other issues on this PC?

Comment: It seems to stay frozen forever. I have to click the X to close the window. This is a fresh install so I don' have any other issues.

Answer (score 2):

Have you gone through and done all the further updates after installing SP3?

There are also service packs for Office too that may fix any bugs that Office has with XP SP3, install these too and see if that fixes the issue.